# Select React Input

Tags: reactjs, antd

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
function something() {
  return (
    <Input.Password name="password" id="password_id"/>
  )
};
```

And I want to call `.blur()` on `<Input.Password/>` outside of the return statement. Will there be any ways to achieve this in a function?

P.S. this is a part of Ant Design's input. Here's the [API](https://ant.design/components/input/#Input-Methods) of the `.blur()` function and the [focus demo](https://ant.design/components/input/#components-input-demo-focus). I essentially want to remove the focus of input by calling the blur function but I don't know how to target the specific input field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way to use boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to use ref and assignt to input
and you can use it any whare with name var.current

```
    import React, {useRef,useEffect} from "react"
    
    
     function something() {
        const ref = useRef(null)
        
        
        useEffect(() => {
          consle.log(ref.current)
          ref.current.focus();
         
    
    , []}
    
    
       
          return (
            <Input.Password ref={ref} name="password" id="password_id"/>
          )
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the docs you linked:

```
<Space direction="vertical">
  <Input.Password placeholder="input password" />
  <Input.Password
   placeholder="input password"
   iconRender={visible => (visible ? <EyeTwoTone /> : <EyeInvisibleOutlined />)}
/>
```

This is a password input with the eye icon that reveals the value on click. But i found nothing about the blur method